# Taxonomy Rewrite Rules Redirecting Instead of Masking

Tags: custom-taxonomy, redirect, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type of ***items*** set up. I also have a taxonomy set up with ***items*** called *categories*.

functions.php code:

```
    regsiter_post_type('items',
                array('labels' => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'Items',
                        'singular_name' => 'Item'
                    ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array
                    ( 
                        'slug' => 'items'
                    ),
                    'supports' => array
                    (
                        'title',
                        'excerpt',
                        'editor',
                        'comments',
                        'revisions',
                        'thumbnail'
                    ),
                    'taxonomies' => array
                    (
                        'categories',
                        'tags'
                    )
                ));
   register_taxonomy ( 'categories', 'items', array('hierarchical' => true,
                    'label' => 'Item Categories',
                    'rewrite' => array
                    (
                        'slug' => 'categories',
                        'hierarchical' => ture
                    )));

require 'rewrites.php'; // load rewrite class
    Rewrites::init(); // call init function in rewrite class
```

rewrites.php code:

```
class Rewrites
    {
        // Start class methods

        public static function init()
        {
            // Rewrite urls
            add_action ( 'generate_rewrite_rules', array( __CLASS__, 'rules' ) );

            add_filter ( 'query_vars', array( __CLASS__, 'vars' ) );
        }

        public static function rules ( $wp_rewrite )
        {
            $new_rules = array();
            $new_rules['categories/(.+?)/view/(.+)/?'] = 'index.php?categories=$matches[1]&view=$matches[2]';

            return $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
        }

        // End class methods
    }
```

So when looking at posts in the taxonomy of categories the url would be:

/categories/%name_of_taxonomy%/

I need to also append to the url to add in query_vars

/categories/%name_of_taxonomy%/view/%type_of_view%/

%type_of_view% would be a couple different options. list, grid etc.

Here is my rewrite rule:

```
[categories/(.+?)/view/(.+)/?] => index.php?categories=$matches[1]&view=$matches[2]
```

But when I go to the url /categories/%name_of_taxonomy%/view/grid/ it redirects back to /categories/%name_of_taxonomy%/

Comment: Ayers - How are you adding that rewrite rule?  Can you update your question with the code?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I have added it

Comment: If I change 'rewrite_rules_array' to 'generate_rewrite_rules' and then use the wp_rewrite object instead of $rules array it won't redirect and leaves the url correct, but shows a 404 page not found wordpress page.

Comment: I was looking for you to provide complete code that someone can test vs. a segment of your code where if we wanted to test it we have to guess at what else you wrote. What you added was a static class method but you didn't add the rest of the class so we can't be sure your error isn't somewhere else.

Comment: Ok I changed the code to show all of what I am using now in my functions.php file and in the class file for rewrites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The rewrites were getting added to the db after the system was reading them from the db. Moved the code and it worked!